# Why this code printing wrong prime numbers?

Tags: javascript, function, loops

"I think problem is in  for loop. Because i have used same "j" to iteration in both function's loop."
I wanted to print all prime number from 1-100.
I think all code is good. But it kept showing output other than prime numbers.

I can't find answers myself . And no other places has written answer. Please help me out here. I want to understand this problem.

```js
var n = 100;

var prime1 = new Array();


//producing prime number upto 97
function primeNumber() {
  for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
    if (countRemainder(j) == 2) {
      prime1.push(j);

    }
  }
}
primeNumber();

console.log(prime1);


function countRemainder(n) {
  var count = 0;
  for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
    if (n % j == 0) {
      count++;
    }

  }
  return count;

}
```

[image: screenshot array output]

Comment: Your `j` has different scope than you think it has. I recommend to always run your code in [Strict Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)

Comment: @TiiJ7 I have no idea, what Strict Mode is.
Thanks for recommending me this valuable resource.

Comment: I remember a teacher telling her students: to write a book, you need to write many pages. To write a page, you need to write many paragraphs. To write a paragraph you need to know how to write a sentence. To write a sentence, you need to know the grammar. To know the grammar, you need to study. Sometimes students are willing to write a book without studying the grammar. That is nice in principle, but doesn't work well, most of the times.

Comment: @SC1000 So thoughtful . I learned my lesson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was indeed happening because you were using the same variable in both `for` loops.

When you declare a variable like `j = 0;` and not like `var j = 0;` the variable will be added to global scope (instead of the scope you are in, so every other scope can see and alter that variable).

If your script is running in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), then this will throw an error, instead of adding the variable to the global scope.

So just add `var` before each `j` declaration.

```js
var n = 100;

var prime1 = new Array();


//producing prime number upto 97
function primeNumber() {
  for (var j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
    if (countRemainder(j) == 2) {
      prime1.push(j);
    }
  }
}

primeNumber();

console.log(prime1);

function countRemainder(n) {
  var count = 0;
  for (var j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
    if (n % j == 0) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: Try using let declaration to avoid all the function scope/auto declare scope issue

Comment: @vun There is no indication that OP is using ES6, so I don't want to add any functionality that might not be compatible. Also, `var` will do just fine for this case, since there aren't any asynchronous operations in the script.

Answer (score 0):

Use "let" to declare "j" correctly.

```
function primeNumber() {
  for (let j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
    if (countRemainder(j) == 2) {
      prime1.push(j);

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var n = 100;

var prime1 = new Array();


//producing prime number upto 97
function primeNumber() {
  for (var j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
    if (countRemainder(j) == 2) {
      prime1.push(j);

    }
  }
}
primeNumber();

console.log(prime1);


function countRemainder(n) {
  var count = 0;
  for (var j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
    if (n % j == 0) {
      count++;
    }

  }
  return count;

}
```